# Convert PostgreSQL Polygon to PostGIS POLYGON

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon

I have an existing table in postgres which contains a plain old posgresql polygon.  I have added a new column using

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','fences','geom',4326,'POLYGON',2);
```

I would like to populate this GIS column with the polygon data from the existing column.

The existing column is called poly and the data looks like the following:

```
"((-74.026142,40.636264),(-74.026142,40.636438),(-74.025818,40.636438),(-74.025818,40.636264),(-74.026142,40.636264))"
```

Is there a query I can run that will pull that poly field convert it to a postgis polygon and insert it into the new geom column?

Comment: The existing column looks like [Well-Known Text (WKT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) for polygons, except that it's missing the POLYGON keyword, and it has extra parentheses around coordinate pairs. If this is formed correctly, you can use `ST_GeomFromText`. See also `regexp_replace`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an elegant solution, but you could try to convert `Polygon` string representation into `WKT` and use `ST_GeomFromText`

```
select ST_GeomFromText(
    'POLYGON ' || 
    regexp_replace(
        '((-74.026142,40.636264),(-74.026142,40.636438),(-74.025818,40.636438),(-74.025818,40.636264),(-74.026142,40.636264))', 
        '\,(?=[0-9])', ' ', 'g') 
)
```

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this.  Thanks for the suggestion.